# java vs. php in html form using post

Tags: java, php, html, spring-mvc, post

I need send a form from php to java using the method post and curl.
I'm having problems to fetch a list of objects in php when I submit the form. I would like to know if is possible to do it like in Spring MVC (specifying attribute name in the form)

```
<form method="post" action="group_create.php">
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[0].name" value="753" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[1].name" value="752" />
        <br />        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Encoding method:

```
<?php
    http_build_query($_POST);
?>
```

Current curl url:

```
javaserver/app/groups/create?name=Administrator&users[0]=Tom&users[1]=Myke
```

Necessary curl url:

```
javaserver/app/groups/create?name=Administrator&users[0].name=Tom&users[1].name=Myke
```

My DTO's:

```
public class GroupDTO {

    private String name;
    private List<UserDTO> users;

    public GroupDTO()
    {
        this.users = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
    }

}

public class UserDTO {

    private String name;

}
```

Spring MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("secure/groups")
public class GroupsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelMap create(GroupDTO dto)
    {
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();

        //CODE TO DO ANYTHING

        return map;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<form method="post" action="group_create.php">
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[0].name" value="753" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[1].name" value="752" />
        <br />        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</form>
```

To this:

```
<form method="post" action="group_create.php">
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[0]" value="753" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="users[1]" value="752" />
        <br />        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The ".name" part is not needed for the form to operate properly.

Comment: But when I submit using a jsp page to Servlet, it is fetching correctly users[0].name